# How to use session data (auth) in the Laravel routes page

Tags: php, laravel

We have a large website with many pages.  Almost all of them require the user to log in.  Instead of specifying "Auth" on every single page, or on every single controller, I would like to set the routes based on if the user is logged in, like this:

```
// in web.php
if (Auth::isLoggedIn()) {
    Route::get('/', function () { return view('pages/dashboard'); });
    ... lots more
}
```

The reason I can't do this is because Auth uses sessions, and sessions are not yet initialized in web.php, since it is done as middleware which is not run yet at this point.

I'm using Laravel 8, I believe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can group the route that need the user to be logged in, then use [auth](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes) middleware
for the grouped routes:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        //
    });

    Route::get('/', function () { return view('pages/dashboard'); });
});
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!

Comment: As an additional comment, you can customize the 403/forbidden route/page to redirect to different pages depending the original request.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Laravel's [Route middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#protecting-routes). Route middleware can be used to only allow authenticated users to access a given route.

Comment: No. If you check the other answer, it explain better how to bulk (using group).